# Trying to make a Python project requirements version-free

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine a project `MyLibrary` which used to have its own `requirements.txt` file specifying all the versions needed by each of the dependencies...

```
lib_a==0.1
lib_b==0.11
lib_c==0.1.1
lib_d==0.1.2
lib_e==0.1.8
```

And a project `ChildProject` which happens to have the same kind of setup, with its own `requirements.txt` file and everything.

`ChildProject` uses `MyLibrary` as it needs some common functionality it has. The problem with this two, is that `ChildProject` has a library which is also specified in `MyLibrary`, but with a different version which causes conflict and causing the build to fail.

What I've done to get rid of the problem is to erase the dependencies in `MyLibrary` and specify the minimum and maximum versions for each of the libraries, specifying those in the `setup_requires` property within the `setup()` method...

```
setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr', 'pytest-runner'],
    install_requires=[
        'lib_a>=0,<1',
        'lib_b>=0,<2',
        'lib_c>=0,<3',
        'lib_d>=0,<4',
        'lib_e>=0,<5'
    ],
    pbr=True,
)
```

And here is where I get lost...

Should I remove `requirements.txt` in `MyLibrary` and leave all the versioning to child projects using ?

If so, how do I know that `ChildProject` is specifying **all** of the needed dependencies? What if I miss to specify `lib_a` in `ChildProject`?

Does the latest version that complies with the `setup_requires` constraints gets automatically installed or how does it work? (I ask this because AFAIK, `install_requires` just specified the constraints but doesn't include any library whatsoever in the project).

Comment: You can build MyLibrary first (as a dependency on your setup.py inside ChildProject), then the next dependency in ChildProject would be the conflicting package used in MyLibrary (I would assume it would force a new install on that one with the version specified in ChildProject). As to whether this will uninstall the previous version and MyLibrary will still work... I am not sure, it might BUILD at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General suggestions for managing deps versions:

- **libraries** dont't *pin* versions (i.e. either `install_requires` doesn't have version at all, or loose restrictions, i.e. `<4`). That's what you have already
- **applications** can do whatever needed. In reality, it's highly recommended to pin your dependencies to some exact version (ant better yet — provide hash, to save yourself from forged libs). Reason for this — you can not guarantee 3rd-party libraries to follow [semver](https://semver.org/). Which means that having `>2, <3` in your `requirements.txt` may lead to broken build/deployment, because 3rd party lib released `2.5` which appears to be backward-incompatible with `2.4`. So, you must do you best to avoid breaking builds by just re-building in different time. In other words, your build should be idempotent on PyPI state.

  In general — you pin version to some state, test your application and commit/save/build/however you deliver. Some time later, you're revising versions (i.e. to update framework or address security patch), updating version in `requirements.txt`, testing your app with new deps state, if there's no conflicts/broken parts, you "freeze" that state with pinned versions, and build/deploy/etc. This kind of loop gives you space to occasionally update your requirements to stay up to date, and at the same time you have code that will not be broken by just re-installing dependencies.

If you're looking to easier dep management with version, I suggest taking a look at [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)